# save state of an item in recyclerview when scrolled out of the view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my project i have a recyclerView which contains at most 20 items. In the row template i have a text view and a button which is hidden initially and on the recyclerview item click the visibility of the button is toogled. The problem is when the button in the first row is shown and if it is scrolled out of the view and then scrolled back the button is invisible again without calling toogle visibility.How can i save the sate of objects in recycler view when it is scrolled out of the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

used a hash map to store states. when the button is clicked the hashmap is updated with the position by calling  `getPosition()`  and the visibility

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
                Btn.setVisibility(Btn.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
                statesMap.put(getPosition(),Btn.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE );
            }
```

and then read the values from the hash map in

`onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position)`

by passing the position

```
holder.Btn.setVisibility(statesMap.get(position) != null && statesMap.get(position) != false ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
```

Comment: hey, I want to implement the same, but getting error. Can you answer it on my question, my adapter class is uploaded there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63332600/android-recycler-view-download-button-problem

Answer (score 3):

Your RecyclerView list items get their state from the objects in the List/Array they are based on the objects used by to your adapter class.

If you want to save a checked state you can add a boolean field to your object class to set and hold the value so that when your adapter, update this on click and set the visibility of the button accordingly.

Instead of Using Strings in your ArrayList use a simple object class to hold the String and an additional boolean value for the state of the button visibility.

Such a class could look like this

```
        class Items {
        String myString;
        boolean visibility;

        public String getMyString(){
            return myString;
        }

        public boolean isVisible(){
            return visibility;
        }

        public void setVisibility(boolean visibility){
            this.visibility = visibility;
        }
    }
```

In your RecyclerView you will have a method to set the value of the list items, I've never used it but I believe it is called bindView? Here where you set the text value of your list item also set the visibility according to the value returned by item.getVisibility() and set it when you call the onClick method of your button.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: i am not using any object class. I'm just using an array list.

Comment: An ArrayList of what?

Comment: an array of strings, just to populate the rows

Comment: i used a hash map to store states. thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

You can use shared preference for this purpose

onRecyclerViewItemClick insert key value in share preference where key should be position and value should be true/false

and in your adapter implement if condition where item view created like

```
if(sharedpreferences.contains(String.valueof(position)) && sharedpreferences.getString(String.valueof(position), "").equals("true")){

//button visible

}

else{
 // button gone/invisible
}
```

Hope this would help you

Comment: adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() is used to Notify any registered observers that the data set has changed.as per the official documentation.it is not used for saving any state. You can read more at [this link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged())

Comment: @sony You were right on that point. I updated my answer Please have a look

Comment: thanks for the idea of shared preferences.i used a hash map to store state. Thanks for your time

Comment: sir i want the answer of this, i create and set button visibility also but whenever activity is restarted we need to set visibility again. I want to implement your answer but dont know how. Heres my question and adapter class. could you please help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63332600/android-recycler-view-download-button-problem